# Как плавно двигать круг в произвольном направлении, например на 110 градусов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pygame, рисование

У меня есть круг:

```
pygame.draw.circle(sc, ORANGE, (x, y), r)
```

На каждой итерации я изменяю его:
**`x`** или **`y`** на **`+1`** или **`-1`**:

```
x += 1
y += 1
```

Таким образом я могу перемещать его примерно так:

```
\|/
-o-
/|\
```

Получается я могу переместить свой круг на `45`, `90`, `135`, `180` градусов и тд.

---

Собственно вопрос: 
**как же мне переместить мой круг например на 110 градусов**? 
Если у меня поверхность состоит из пикселей (квадратов) и я могу перемещаться только, как в примере?

```
\|/
-o-
/|\
```

Просто сделать `x += 1.5` Я не могу, тк `pygame.draw.circle` принимает только целые числа.

Эта тема очень сложна для меня и мне было сложно сформировать вопрос, но надеюсь смог объяснить правильно.

Полный код:

```
import pygame

def main():
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    ORANGE = (255, 150, 100)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60

    WIN_WIDTH = 800
    WIN_HEIGHT = 600

    pygame.init()

    sc = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))

    # радиус и координаты круга
    r = 90
    x = WIN_WIDTH//2
    y = WIN_HEIGHT//2

    while 1:
        sc.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.circle(sc, ORANGE, (x, y), r)
        pygame.display.update()

        for i in pygame.event.get():
            if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        x += 1
        y -= 1

        # Круг двигается на 135 градусов, а хотелось бы например на 110 градусов

        clock.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] . 
NameError: name 'Enum' is not defined

Comment: @S.Nick извиняюсь, исправил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

да, вам надо манипулировать значениями `x` и `y`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import pygame

def main():
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    GRAY = (125, 125, 125)
    LIGHT_BLUE = (64, 128, 255)
    GREEN = (0, 200, 64)
    YELLOW = (225, 225, 0)
    PINK = (230, 50, 230)
    ORANGE = (255, 150, 100)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 20                                                     # 60

    WIN_WIDTH = 800
    WIN_HEIGHT = 600

    pygame.init()

    sc = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))

    # радиус и координаты круга
    r = 10                                                       # 90
    x = WIN_WIDTH//2
    y = WIN_HEIGHT//2

    while 1:
        sc.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.circle(sc, ORANGE, (x, y), r)
        pygame.display.update()
        for i in pygame.event.get():
            if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        x += 1 
        y -= 3                                                  # + 3        # <<<=====<

        # Круг двигается на 135 градусов, а хотелось бы например на 110 градусов
        # 90 + (90 - 45) = 135
        # 90 + (90 - x ) = 110   x = 180 - 110 = 70

        clock.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите медленно двигать, а принимает только целые числа, то уменьшите FPS. А так, чтобы переместить на определенное расстояние, можно использовать цикл for. К примеру

```
for i in range(10):
    x += 1
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, не понял, как фпс влияет на поворот? Мне нужно как-то сдвигать мой круг например на 110 градусов.

Comment: FPS поменять если нужно сменить скорость я имел ввиду, а так используйте цикл for, который запускается при определенных условиях

Comment: А так, вы можете написать к примеру `x += 1` `y += 3`

Comment: x += 1 и y += 3 сколько это будет в градусах? Есть какая-то формула?

Comment: Это на 1 пиксель в право, на 3 вверх. Дальше просто посчитать уже или проверять методом тыка